# ColdFusion - How to prevent direct access of webpage

Tags: coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion.

How can I prevent users from directly accessing a webpage?

i.e. when a user enters - "www.google.com/thispage" the user **should redirect** back to "www.google.com". The users can only access "www.google.com/thispage" via a link on "www.google.com".

OR

i.e. when a user enters - "www.google.com/thispage" the application should **log out**. The users can only access "www.google.com/thispage" via a link on "www.google.com".

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [onRequestStart](http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/). You can check which page they are requesting and whether or not they are logged in, then redirect using `cflocation` if they are not able to access the page they requested.

Comment: Add a parameter to the URL from your landing page with an encrypted string and then decrypt it on the page to make sure it's valid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic/too broad because it does not demonstrate any effort was made to resolve the issue or indicate what issues or error messages were encountered so far.